# Form validation with flash messages in express js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to validate a form in express js before i post it onto the mongodb which i am using as a backend. My user.js for registration page looks something like this -

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
userreg.register(
// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
new userreg({
  firstname: req.body.firstname,
  lastname: req.body.lastname,
  username: req.body.email,
  usn: req.body.usn, // validate so that no space is taken or else request modal wont work
  course: req.body.course,
}),
req.body.password,
(err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.render('register', { user: 'error' });
  } else {
    console.log('no error');
    res.render('submit-success', { username: req.body.firstname });
  }
}
);
});
```

and my register.ejs looks something like this -

```
<form class="user" action = '/users/register' method="POST">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleLastName" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputUSN" name="usn"  placeholder="USN">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class=" form-control selectpicker" name="course">
                  <optgroup label="Course"></optgroup>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>Course</option>
                    <option value="mca">Computer Applications</option>
                    <option value="mba">Business Administration</option>
                  </optgroup>
                </select>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
              <input type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary btn-user" value="Register">
            </div>
          </form>
```

By going through many sources on the internet(since i'm very very new to express js and im doing it as a part of my college project and since i can't consult any teachers for assistance during lockdown times) , I got to know that the validation part has to be implemented in user.js. Please help me with the code for validation and also displaying flash messages if field empty for atleast one field so that i can have a start atleast.

Thank you in advance

EDIT :

I Used the express-validator and ended up with the following changes -

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 } }));
app.use(flash());
});




app.get('/flash', function (req, res) {
// Set a flash message by passing the key, followed by the value, to 
req.flash().
req.flash('info', 'There is an Error!')
res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
// Get an array of flash messages by passing the key to req.flash()
res.render('index', { messages: req.flash('info') });
});

const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

router.post('/register', [
check('firstname', 'Please enter your first 
name').exists().trim().escape().not().isEmpty(),
check('lastname', 'Please enter your last 
name').exists().trim().not().isEmpty(),
check('username', 'Please enter an 
email').exists().trim().not().isEmpty(),
check('usn', 'Please enter USN').exists().trim().not().isEmpty(),
check('course', 'Please enter Course').exists().trim().not().isEmpty(),
check('password', 'Please enter 
password').exists().trim().not().isEmpty(),

], (req, res) => {
const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
req.flash('message', `${errors}`);
res.redirect('/users/register');
} else {
userreg.register(
  // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
  new userreg({
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
    username: req.body.email,
    usn: req.body.usn, // validate so that no space is taken or else 
    request modal wont work
    course: req.body.course,
    })),


  res.render('submit-success', { username: req.body.firstname });
  }

  }
  );
```

And as a result , the if (!errors.isEmpty()) is being invoked but there is no flash message being displayed. Am i missing something else ?

Comment: For the flash message, you just need to define global variables. hoe did you define your root file

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using [connect-flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash).

```js
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
    
router.post('/register', [
    check('firstname', 'Please enter your first name').exists().trim().escape().not().isEmpty(),
    check('lastname', 'Please enter your last name').exists().trim().not().isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please enter an email').exists().trim().not().isEmpty(),
    // ...
], (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
       req.flash('message', `${errors}`);
       res.redirect('register');
    }
    else {
        // your code here!
    }
});
```

You might want to consider creating middleware to handle validation errors, to make your code cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Koodies , i'll give this a try.